# Why isn't my activity visible in Android "all apps"

Tags: android, android-activity, splash-screen

I am trying to create an splash screen activity which will do some pre required Network calls before the real app starts. However, the app icon does not show in "all apps" on android. Can you help me? Here is my manifest code related to the activity:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/rtf" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/tiff" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/bmp" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/gif" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/postscript" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/msword" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

The complete application code from the manifest looks like this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyD1e3EbexMClXfkyULNViJlOPgeubzZdfI" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrintJobActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectPrinterOptionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_printer_options"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:parentActivityName=".PrintJobActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PrintJobActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrintRangeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_print_range"
        android:parentActivityName=".PrintJobActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".PrintJobActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectPrinterMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_printer_map"
        android:parentActivityName=".SelectPrinterOptionsActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SelectPrinterOptionsActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PrintPreviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_print_preview"
        android:parentActivityName=".SelectPrinterOptionsActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SelectPrinterOptionsActivity" />
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".network.NetworkService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".OrderInfoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_info_activitty" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".OrderDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_order_details" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TermsAndConditionsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_terms_and_conditions" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/rtf" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/tiff" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/bmp" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/gif" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/postscript" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/msword" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: what about the <application android:icon="@drawable/icon"...   part of your menifest file?

Comment: I'd also remove the `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />` attribute and set that one to the Main Activity (the one launched by the Splash Activity)

Comment: @DerGolem I didn't cuiet catch that one. I should remove category.default and then what?

Comment: Your Splash Activity is the LAUNCHER one (the one which launches the application). Your Main Activity is then the DEFAULT one (the Activity which serves as the BASE for all the other ones and as a Fragment container). Also, I don't catch why do you have the Splash Activity as a provider for all those data types... And also has an intent of `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />`

Comment: @DerGolem Sorry but it didn't work. I have all the data type because I want a single entrance to the app. Before the app works I have to check some online parameters and that is what I am doing in the splash activity.

Comment: But once the Splash Activity is **finished**, you will loose all those data types.

Comment: @DerGolem What do you mean with "Loose all"? I am catching the uri from the selected file and parsing it to the .MainActivity

Comment: Well, if you don't need the data types later, it's OK like that.

Comment: ok, thanks. I still haven't solved the problem though :(

Comment: @DerGolem I have found the problem, but not the solution. The problem is the data types. I think the app launcher is removed from all apps, because it does not have thouse data types. Is there a Work around for this?

Comment: Maybe, moving the datatypes and the VIEW intent filter to the Main Activity could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must create separate `intent-filter` to each action:

```
 <activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/rtf" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/tiff" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/bmp" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/gif" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/postscript" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/msword" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.ms-excel" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Solved it very nicely :)

Answer (score 0):

Were your **android:logo** or android:icon  look the above:

```
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    **android:logo="ic_luncher.png"**
    android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: My icon is on the application level and looks like this: 'android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"'

Comment: I just added the complete application code to the question.